# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have done encryption and decryption using private and public keys successfully, But I face this error when I tried to apply the RSA decryption using RSAPrivateCrtKey instead of RSAPrivateKey.

The error is:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
----------------DECRYPTION COMPLETED------------
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at lab6.RSACRT.rsaDecrypt(RSACRT.java:132)
    at lab6.RSACRT.main(RSACRT.java:63)
```

The code is as mentioned below. Thanks in advance!.

```
    private byte[] rsaDecrypt(RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaprivateCrtKey, byte[] ciphertext) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("\n----------------DECRYPTION STARTED------------");
            byte[] descryptedData = null;
            int cipher1= ciphertext.length;
            System.out.println(cipher1);
            try {
                RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
                descryptedData = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
                System.out.println("Decrypted Data: " + new String(descryptedData));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            System.out.println("----------------DECRYPTION COMPLETED------------");
            return descryptedData;      
        }



            public RSAPrivateCrtKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                ObjectInputStream ois = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                    BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();
                    BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();

                    //Get Private Key
                    RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec rsaPrivateCrtKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent);
                    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateCrtKeySpec);

                    return (RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    if(ois != null){
                        ois.close();
                        if(fis != null){
                            fis.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *`new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent);`* - Is your problem. Please read the documentation about what should be passed here and then do that.

Comment: You also may want to look at **try with resources** to more easily handle the streams and RSA with OAEP padding to make decryption more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Artjom already mentioned your call to the constructor of `RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec` is wrong. What you seem to need is just a normal `RSAPrivateKeySpec` without the parameters required to perform calculations based on the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT).

What you now have is:

```
//Get Private Key
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec rsaPrivateCrtKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateCrtKeySpec);

return (RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey;
```

while what you need is:

```
//Get Private Key
RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateKeySpec);

return (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey;
```

and then you also need to change the return type of the method to `RSAPrivateKey`of course.

---

Alternatively if there are more objects representing the CRT parameters you may need more variables and more calls to `(BigInteger) ois.readObject()`.

---

RSA CRT is about 4 times faster than plain RSA (and has different timing attack characteristics, but I suppose that's a more advanced topic).